# How to quickly move to the end of a code block in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: javascript, html, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

Is there a keystroke combo to quickly move the cursor to the end of a code block or past a closing tag (in HTML document)?  For example, you are done editing or filling in some function/class/tag and you just want to quickly navigate without using arrow keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aptana is built off Eclipse.
So often they share the same shortcuts.
What you are appear to be looking for is the Home and End keys (if you're on windows).

Just checked for Mac its (Apple) Command + Left or Right on the arrow keys.

More info available here:
http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html

Answer (score 1):

To navigate from on opening/closing parenthesis or bracket to its partner, select the opening/closing parenthesis or bracket and hit Ctrl+Shift+P.